# Dart HTML5 Canvas Library?

Tags: dart

I wanted to know if there were a Canvas external library for DART like Fabric.js ?
If it doesn't exist is there a project to make one ? Cause I'm thinking of starting this project, but I would prefer joining a existing project on GIT.
Or maybe there is things integrated in DART that I don't know ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've not worked with Fabric.js, but after taking a look at the website, I'd point you to the projects listed below.  Neither project is exactly what you are looking for, but should give you a starting point.

2D (Flash object model) - The project changed to StageXL
https://github.com/bp74/StageXL

WebGL
https://github.com/johnmccutchan/spectre

Comment: WebGl is more for 3d, but maybe it's interesting to take a look !
I didn't really check that one, I'll try it to see if it can fit my needs. Thanks

Comment: @Shadowbob Yes I included that one just to give another example of canvas usage with Dart. :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any serious Canvas abstraction libs for Dart but maybe these two projects could provide a good inspiration foundation to create one.

1. [Drag & Draw approach](https://github.com/financeCoding/DragDrawSquaresCanvas2D)
2. [Animation approach](https://github.com/Fiveisprime/Dart-Animation)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll check that later, I'll look at WebGL for the moment.